# Google Navigate does not announce the street name on my phone, but it does on my tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-maps-navigation

I have a Galaxy III running Android 4.1.1.  When I use Navigate on my phone it will announce the turns but without the street names.

I also have a Nexus 7, running Android 4.2.1 and when I use Navigate on that device, it does announce the street names (provided it has an internet connection --- which it gets from my phone ironically)

Is there anyway to get the phone to also announce the street names?